# How to manage the focal length with Aframe

Tags: three.js, camera, aframe

I building a web application with Aframe.js framework build over Three.js, main core of this application it's to look 360 render image that 3D artist done with Unreal Engine.

Everything works good, but I need to manage the focal length of the camera to be able the designers to change it directly on the application.

With Aframe I see the camera entity have only these parameters:

- active
- far
- fov
- near
- spectator
- zoom

There are some way to change the focal length?

I see also this formula, but I need the sensor size in this case
field of view = 2 * arctan(sensor size / (focal length * 2))

Some idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setFocalLength()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setFocalLength) function of the `THREE.PerspectiveCamera` used in the scene:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("focal-changer", {
    init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener("loaded", () => { // wait until loaded
        const camera = this.el.camera; // grab the THREE.Perspective camera
        camera.setFocalLength(1); // change the focal lenght
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene focal-changer>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```